# I was reading documentation on telegram.updater.ext and saw a polling method. This method has a timout parameter. Can someone explain this?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
start_polling(poll_interval=0.0, timeout=10, clean=None, bootstrap_retries=- 1, read_latency=2.0, allowed_updates=None, drop_pending_updates=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `timeout` parameter is the time in seconds that the bot will wait for a response from the server. If the server does not respond within that time, the bot will assume that the server is down and will try to reconnect.